# How do I find source file for GUI loading from remote Linux machine?

Tags: linux

I have 4 similar Linux devices running on a private network. The Linux is custom-developed by the manufacturer. Each device has the same browser-based GUI/application which I can access via its respective IP address (ie, 10.1.10.x).  I also have full access to each device via PuTTY, SSH, etc.

Upgrading to the latest Linux distro on one device, I have lost the ability to access the GUI/application. I would like to determine where the GUI/app is loading from on one of the functioning devices to help me troubleshoot the problem device.  How do I determine the folder/file that runs the GUI/app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming root access and a more or less fully functional userspace, I would start by looking at the output of `netstat -anpt | grep LISTEN` to identify the PID of the program listening on port 80/443.  Then I would look at `ps -ef | grep <pid found in step 1>` to see the full path of the binary.  If it's something in `/usr/bin` or other standard path, I would look for configuration in `/etc/`, if it's something vendor-installed in e.g. `/opt/` or `/usr/local/` I would look for configuration in nearby directories.

You can also dig around in `/proc/<PID>/fd` to see which files the process has open.  That can sometimes give you an indication of where to look for config files.

Another relevant path of investigation is to look for startup scripts/unit files.  Grepping for the process name in `/etc/init.d/`(old style) or the output of `systemctl`(modern) and reading the relevant script/unit file (`less`/`systemctl cat`) can provide useful information.

Comment: Appreciate it, Peder.  The first two steps in the first paragraph of your answer gave me exactly what I was looking for.